# I have no idea how sound design works

Tags: sound-design, technology

I hope this is the right place to post this. I have no idea how to develop music using software like lmms. I'm a high school graduate going into entertainment industry. I really love music and everything about it. To prepare for my major I've been helping out in my local church with the audio. Most of what I do is mute and unmute mics, adjust the volume of a speaker, and once in awhile adjust the EQs when I know what to adjust. I enjoy editing and producing music digitally so I started by downloading LMMS. I use to use musescore as my writing tool but it became increasingly difficult to create a proper playback. I started watching tutorials on YouTube, but when they started to get into changing instruments and adding effects I got completely lost. I need to find a way to learn the basics of digital sound editing so I can produce my own music, but everywhere I turn there isn't anyone who can teach at a simpler level.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't really a question.  Additionally, the implied question is probably too broad to be 'answered'.  Perhaps take a look around this site for questions tagged with [beginner].  (You can type beginner with those square brackets in the search field to search by tags)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this helps, but I started out by making beats using flstudio, which has some cool visual plug-ins that make it easier to internalize the function of all of the different tools and effects, and applying them to a track that I made felt like it made learning about them even more satisfying, so I thought that was a great introduction into the basics of sound design. There's a guy on youtube who has great intro tutorials for flstudio, his channel is BusyWorksBeats. Hope this helps!